# VB.net - Check if registry key exists doesn't work correctly?

Tags: vb.net

I'm confused cause I made a function which should detect a registry key on load.

Pretty simple:

```
Dim regVersion As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\xx", True)
If regVersion Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("lol")
Else
    MsgBox("xD")
End If
```

But even if the Subkeyfolder "xx" in CurrentVersion exists, it just displays "lol". How is that possible? Am I just retarded and missing something? xD

Comment: `regVersion ` is just declared, there is nothing assigned to it, so the code is working correctly.

Comment: Uhhh sorry but what are you trying to tell me?

Comment: where do you set regversion equal to the registrykey object that opensubkey returns..?

Comment: Nvm I fixed it now ;)

Comment: Post your fix/resolution So that others can learn when they have the same problem. You can also mark it the answer too if it resolves your issue.